# Flat spotify free icon next to trash icon on Macos

Tags: macos, dock, icon

I recently noticed this yesterday, I deleted it from persistent apps yesterday, and that seemed to solve the problem. However, today when I opened up my mac again I saw the icon again. I can click and drag it but it doesn't go in trash. There doesn't seem to be any Spotify apps on my computer apart from the normal one. I am not sure where the "spotify free" came from. How do I get rid of it?

[image: tiny icon next to trash can]

Comment: I have the same issue but mine says "premium" next to it.

Comment: *RIGHT* click on the 'icon' and see if you can remove it from any menu that is displayed. It may be something that Spotify installed to get you to spend more $$ with them. There is likely a startup item or launch agent that is putting it there. you may have to take it up with Spotify...